# How can I tell if Display Stream Compression being used or not?

Tags: video, gpu, monitor

I am using windows pc with Nvidia DSC supported graphics card. Monitor with DSC support. And unknown displayport cable. Set up 4k 24bit/px 144Hz. Is DSC on?

Searched the internet and found nothing. The only thing I got is DSC auto-enabled when it needed. And no way to tell if it's being used or not right now.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your monitor has DisplayPort 2.0 or 2.1, at 4k 144Hz full RGB, the answer will always be "yes, DSC is used", because DP 1.4(a) tops at 4k 120Hz full RGB due to limited bandwidth.

If you're on nVidia GPU, you can also try checking if you have nVidia Image Scaling, DRS or Integer Scaling available. Those are unavailable with DSC for some reason (the Image Scaling option, for example, becomes just Image Sharpening, the scaling portion is disabled). Though this is not a 100% reliable test (they can be unavailable for other reasons, too).